# i have a table like below i need which person got highest total?

Tags: sql

```
name    T       E       M       S        SS
nelson  10  20  30  40  50
felix   60  70  80  40  50
leon    60  30  80  90  10
```

i need name , total mark scored by three and who gets highest total

Comment: Specify the expected result!

Answer (score 0):

This below code will give you the total,

```
SELECT name, SUM(T+E+m+S+SS) as Total
FROM yourtable
Group by name
```

To get the highest scorer you could use order by and top 1,

```
Select top(1) * 
From(SELECT name, SUM(T+E+m+S+SS) as Total
FROM yourtable
Group by name)a
Order by Total DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I think want something like this:

```
select name,  (T + E + M + S + SS) as total
from t
order by total desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Note that not all databases support the standard `fetch first` clause.  Some use `select top` or `limit` or even other mechanisms.